# Consider the system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the system of linear equations

$x_1$+$6x_2$ +$x_3$=-4

$ax_2$+$x_3$= 1

$-2x_1$+$23x_2$+$ax_3$=3

(a) Write down the coefficient matrix A of the system and find det(A) as a
function of the variable a.

I found the determinant of the 3x3 matrix and I got $a^2$+2a-35.

(b) Determine the two numerical values of a for which the system does not have
a unique solution.
For this I solved the quadratic and got $a=-7$ and $a=5$.

(c) For both values of a found in 3(b), solve the corresponding system.

**My question:**

**For part c should I have two corresponding systems that I must solve, one which has the -7 subbed in for a and solve it. Then another corresponding system with r subbed in for a. Or should I just have one system with -7 subbed in for one a and 5 subbed in for the other a ?**

Comment: The first one is what you want

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Comment: Infinetely many solutions for $a=-7$ and no solution for $a=5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't confirmed that you computed $\det(A)$ correctly, but I will assume that you did.

If $\det(A) = a^2 + 2a - 35 = (a + 7)(a - 5) = 0$, then indeed there is no unique solution to the system.

The problem then asks to solve the system when $\det(A) = 0$ or in other words, when $a = -7$ or $a = 5$.

So now what you want to do is solve both of these:

\begin{align*}
x_1 + 6x_2 + x_3 &= -4, \\
0x_1 - 7x_2 + x_3 &= 1, \\
-2x_1 + 23x_2 - 7x_3 &= 3.
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
x_1 + 6x_2 + x_3 &= -4, \\
0x_1 + 5x_2 + x_3 &= 1, \\
-2x_1 + 23x_2 + 5x_3 &= 3.
\end{align*}

Again, I won't solve these systems for you, but one of two things will happen: you will either get a solution for $x_i$ that depends on a parameter $t$ (i.e. infinitely many solutions) or you will get a contradiction which will mean there are no solutions.

Comment: thank you for that @politeproofs